# How can I add a static block in product page before reviews?

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, rwd-theme, product-view

I'm using default RWD theme. I'm trying to add my static block in product page between additional information tab and product reviews tab.[image: static block in product page between additional information tab and product reviews tab]

I tried to add something like this in my local.xml file but it doesn't work:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="cms/block" name="my_block_name" before="reviews">
        <action method="setBlockId"><id>my_block_name</id></action>
      </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a lok at how the review tab has been added in `review.xml` of the rwd theme, you find:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

You can use the same method to add any other block as a tab in your own module (or local.xml of your theme). For a static block, it can look like this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="cms/block" name="product.whatever" as="whatever" after="additional">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Whatever</value></action>
            <action method="setBlockId"><id>my_whatever_block_id</id></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

`after="additional"` will move it before the reviews tab because the core modules are always loaded first.